# basic ethereum setup help

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain

What I want to do:

1. Install Ethereum on multiple nodes in a network. I have some Linux machines for this purpose already.
2. I want to have a client (let's call it `myApp.exe`). `myApp.exe` gets user inputs and stores it. I want to use blockchain for this. Want to save the data in the Ehtereum nodes.

I am running some initial prototypes to get this setup ready.

1. I am getting some geth clients installed on some Linux machines in our network - these are for simulating the ethereum nodes I guess.
2. on the box where myApp.exe runs, how do I ensure it sends the data to the ethereum node? can I do it by installing web3 on that box? My understanding is web3 can talk to the geth instance on the Ethereum node.

Please confirm if my understanding and above approach is right.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding that you will require web3 to communicate with ethereum node is correct.

If I understood it correctly you want to set up multi-node private ethereum blockchain network. Refer the following article for the same-

https://blockgeeks.com/two-node-setup-of-a-private-ethereum/

Refer the following article for setting up an environment for decetralized application(DAPP) development-

https://medium.com/coinmonks/configuring-ubuntu-and-macos-for-smart-contract-and-dapps-in-ethereum-e6ec329f1a0d